# Filter different lists created by ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have two tabs with different list created by ng-repeat

When I'm filtering second tab - everything works properly, but first one does not work at all.

I now that problem is because of `<ul search-list=".letter" model="search.district">` and `<input id="q" type="text" ng-model="search.district " />`, but `search.district` I need for second tab correct filtering. If you will change `search.district` on `search` - filtering will work on both tabs, but on second tab filtering won't be correct (filter should filters districts, and when we click on `Z` it shows all cities with letter `z`).

So, question is, how to leave `search.district` in my code, and how to make filter works correct in both tabs?

Here is working [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Gcc7U?p=preview)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `startWith` function you assume `expected` is String, but for first panel comparison is an object, change code like this:

```
var e = angular.isString(expected) ? expected.toLowerCase() : expected.district.toLowerCase();
```

Then use `e` variable as `indexOf` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfect!
[Working correct DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/08NKuz?p=preview)